# Is there an easy to use class for sqllite database management for java

Tags: java, android

Is there a prepared class for sqllite in java/android studio to accelerate development like [Medoo](https://medoo.in/) in php?

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/69?sort=created

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you recommend me the easiest one?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you would consider to be easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ORM database libraries. It is some of them:

[GreenDao](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO)

[Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html)

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

There are many third party libraries available for android ORM which can help you  to get rid of boring sql queries and save your time you can find a very detailed comparison of some good ORM libraries here:
[5 best android ORMs](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-best-android-orms/)

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of years, I decided to implement my own database wrapper! As i inspired the idea from Medoo project, I called it [Jedoo](https://github.com/pwwiur/Jedoo).

It has plenty of methods to do things easilly, for example i bring `insert` method.

```
long id = database.insert("users", new Object[][]{
    {"username", "pwwuir"},
    {"type": 4}
});
```